# Why is the method onReceive(...) being called twice in this piece of code?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

##### My Question

I'm rather new to iOS programming. I am currently confused as to why the `onReceive(...)` callback method is being run twice in a row. Could someone enlighten me as to why this is happening?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    
    @State private var listener_toggle_1: Bool = true
    
    @State private var listener_toggle_2: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20, content:
        {
            Text("The following is our 1st toggle")
                .padding()
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
            
            Toggle("The 1st toggle", isOn: $listener_toggle_1)
                .padding()
                .onReceive([self.listener_toggle_1].publisher.first())
                { (value) in
                    print("Toggle #1 has been touched!")
                }
                
            Text("The following is our 2nd toggle")
                .padding()
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
            
            Toggle("The 2nd toggle", isOn: $listener_toggle_2)
                .padding()
                .onReceive([self.listener_toggle_2].publisher.first())
                { (value) in
                    print("Toggle #2 has been touched!")
                }
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider
{
    static var previews: some View
    {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

##### Expected Output

```
(pressed the 1st toggle on the UI)
>>> Toggle #1 has been touched!

(pressed the 2nd toggle on the UI)
>>> Toggle #2 has been touched!
```

##### Actual Output

```
(pressed the 1st toggle on the UI)
>>> Toggle #2 has been touched!
>>> Toggle #1 has been touched!

(pressed the 2nd toggle on the UI)
>>> Toggle #2 has been touched!
>>> Toggle #1 has been touched!
```

What is going on right now?

Comment: This is SwiftUI. I added that tag to your question.

Comment: @DuncanC Ah, yes! Forgot about that part! Thanks for improving the post!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time the `@State` is changed, the view re-renders. Because of how you're creating the publishers (`[self.listener_toggle_1].publisher.first()`), they are getting recreated on each re-render of the view. So, any `@State` change ends up recreating each `Publisher`, thus the double output.

You could avoid this by storing the properties in a view model with `@Published` properties that would persist between view re-renders:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var listener_toggle_1: Bool = true
    @Published var listener_toggle_2: Bool = true
}

struct ContentView: View
{
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20, content:
        {
            Text("The following is our 1st toggle")
                .padding()
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
            
            Toggle("The 1st toggle", isOn: $viewModel.listener_toggle_1)
                .padding()
                .onReceive(viewModel.$listener_toggle_1)
                { (value) in
                    print("Toggle #1 has been touched! \(value)")
                }
                
            Text("The following is our 2nd toggle")
                .padding()
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .heavy, design: .default))
            
            Toggle("The 2nd toggle", isOn: $viewModel.listener_toggle_2)
                .padding()
                .onReceive(viewModel.$listener_toggle_2)
                { (value) in
                    print("Toggle #2 has been touched! \(value)")
                }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you provide me a bit more insight into what exactly `[self.listener_toggle_1].publisher.first()` is doing? Being new to Swift, I am not sure if it's meant to be a capturing group, a list, or god knows what else...

Comment: The brackets create an array, then `.publisher` creates a publisher, then `.first()` publishes the first value, and then finishes.